# When are header based libraries more performant than a statically linked library?

Tags: c++, optimization, linker, g++, ld

When a static library is compiled, the library is optimized by the compiler. When that library is statically linked with another library to produce a resulting executable an optimizing linker will remove the unneeded functionality from the original static library. In doing this the resulting executable is then optimized and only contains the functionality it will need at runtime. Now intuitively by compiling a library separately to the main executable the compiler will have a reduced scope for optimization. This is simply because the compiler does not have access to all source code at one point in time and therefore cannot make global optimizations over your entire executable at compile time. When you use a header only library the code is copied from the library into your source file by the preprocessor and then compiled in one go. This means the compiler could potentially have a much greater scope for optimization, as it can see the entire code at once, and make 'intelligent' decisions based on the code as a whole.

So my **question** is, in what situations would the resulting binary be more performant in a header only library vs a statically linked library??

This question is of course **very** dependant on the compiler/linker in question, so for those answering I am mostly interested in tools from the GNU toolchain.

**Note:** I am **not** interested in answers that talk about templates or meta-programming, as a fair comparison cannot be made between static libraries and header only libraries. I am specifically asking about optimizations during compiling and linking.

Comment: the preprocessor optimizes? this is news to me... I would have thought with lto, there wouldn't be much in it...

Comment: In C++ a header-only library is a set of header files which typically contain lots of templates, which all functions being inline (implicitly or explicitly). The preprocessor is only involved for the actual `#include` directive and potential macro-replacement (which a typical C++ header-only library have few if any).

Comment: Also, a static library is basically a collection of object files, and you link it with other object files, which means the compiler isn't involved, but the *linker* is. Any possible *compiler* optimizations are done before the static library is created or used.

Comment: @Nim you are right... Just did a bit of googling, and that has been a longstanding misconception of mine. But you are right templates are not handled by the preproccessor. I apolgise editing my post now.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am specifically comparing the scope that the compiler has to optimize when comparing a static library vs a header only library. The compiler will only have access to each source file when creating compiling object files and therefore can only make optimizations on that source file. Whereas when using a header only library, the compiler has access to a 'all'  of the code and can therefore optimize based on the entire codebase, rather than individually??

Comment: Since the compiler isn't really involved when linking static libraries (besides creating the involved object files) you have to rely on link-time-optimizations only. With a header-only library the compiler has, as you say, "access" to all the code and can perform other optimizations.

Comment: If the static library is compiled with `-g -O0` and your project is compiled with `-O3` (and / or multiple other optimisations like `-ffast-math`).

Comment: I'm not sure if there is really a useful answer to this, except to measure.  Link  optimization  can a  lot  than  remove  code  days, but in most cases, creating a static library from c++ code is a lossy transformation. So in theory - given the same code - compile time will always be better than link time optimizations. In practice, there are so many heuristics involved that you can hardly predict the outcome and it is my impression, that most optimizers don't really look at the actual c++ code anyway. One question I'd consider is if your compiler can perform PGO with static libraries.